# SDL 2: Game Controller Rumble failing despite claiming rumble is supported?

Tags: c++, controller, sdl-2

SDL2 semi-recently (v2.0.9 and onwards) added [some functions for rumbling the controller for their new "GameController" API](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_GameControllerRumble), and I'm trying to make a simple SDL2 program that, when the user presses a keyboard key, it rumbles whatever controller they have plugged in. However, for some reason, SDL2's not actually able to rumble the controller despite claiming it supports rumble.

According to the docs, "SDL_GameControllerRumble()" returns a 0 on success, and -1 "if rumble isn't supported on this controller". "SDL_GameControllerHasRumble()" is similar, returning either TRUE or FALSE depending on whether the controller in question supports rumble.

Indeed, "SDL_GameControllerHasRumble()" returns true for the controller I'm using to test (a PowerA Xbox Series X controller), and I can confirm using [this site](https://gamepad-tester.com/) the controller has fully functioning rumble. Yet despite this "SDL_GameControllerRumble()" returns -1! Somehow, SDL2 both claims my controller supports rumble, but the actual rumble function fails anyways.

Here's the code I'm using to test:

```
// rumble.cpp
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <cstdio>

int width = 640;
int height = 480;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Rumble Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    SDL_GameController *cont = SDL_GameControllerOpen(0);
    
    if (SDL_GameControllerHasRumble(cont) == SDL_FALSE) {
        printf("No rumble support?\n");
    } else {
        printf("There's rumble support!\n");
    }
    
    bool running = 1;
    while (running) {
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                running = false;
            }
            
            if (event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT) {
                if (event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED) {
                    SDL_GetWindowSize(window, &width, &height);
                    printf("Window resized! %i %i\n", width, height);
                }
            }
            
            if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
                if (SDL_GameControllerRumble(cont, 0xffff, 0xffff, 2000) == -1) {
                    printf("Rumble failed...?\n");
                } else {
                    printf("Rumble success!\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the command I'm compiling with:

```
g++ src/rumble.cpp -o bin/rumble.exe -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lopengl32
```

The SDL2 version I'm using is SDL 2.0.22. Am I missing something?

Comment: `SDL_GetError()`?